# How do I combine map with to_s?

Tags: ruby

I am using Mongoid and retrieving a bunch of `BSON::ObjectId` instances. Ideally, I'd like to convert them to strings upon retrieval. What's the correct syntax? It can be done in two lines like this:

```
foo = Bar.where(:some_id => N).map(&:another_id)
ids_as_strings = foo.map(&:to_s)
```

What's the proper Ruby way to chain `to_s` after the map invocation above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works fine, but don't do it!

```
ids_as_string = Bar.where(:some_id => N).map(&:another_id).map(&:to_s)
```

It looks cool for sure, but think about it, you are doing two maps. A map is for looping over an array, or something else, and will operate in each position, retrieving a new array, or something else, with the results.

So why do two loops if you want to do two operations?

```
ids_as_string = Bar.where(:some_id => N).map {|v| v.another_id.to_s}
```

This should be the way to go in this situation, and actually looks nicer.

Comment: I think that "don't do it" may be too strong advice, but it is good to point out that impact and alternative.

Comment: I don't think "don't do it" is too strong, it's important that developers understand why a solution works, and it's important to strive for best possible performance in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can just chain it directly:

```
ids_as_string = Bar.where(:some_id => N).map(&:another_id).map(&:to_s)
```

I tried this out with a model and I got what you expected, something like:

```
["1", "2", ...]
```